# How can I fix this 'Failed to activate swap /swapfile' error on boot in Xubuntu?

Tags: boot, grub2, xubuntu, swap

When I boot my laptop, I'm seeing:

```
systemd[1]: Failed to activate swap /swapfile.
[FAILED]: Failed to activate swap /swapfile.
[DEPEND]: Dependency failed for swap.
```

I am then taken to the Ubuntu terminal.

I'm using Xubuntu 21.10.

Once I've logged in in the terminal, I am seeing:

```
/usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-motd: 39: cannot create /var/lib/ubuntu/release-upgrader/release-upgrade-available: Read-only file system
mktemp: failed to create file via template '/var/lib/update-notifier/tmp.XXXXXXXXXX': Read-only file system
run-parts: /etc/update-motd.d/95-hwe-eol exited with return code 1
/usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-fsck-at-reboot: 38: cannot create /var/lib/update-notifier/fsck-at-reboot: Read-only file system
cat: /var/lib/update-notifier/fsck-at-reboot: No such file or directory
run-parts: /etc/update-motd.d/98-fsck-at-reboot exited with return code 1
```

How can I repair whatever went wrong?

N.B.: I'm using hibernation, thus I need a 16 GB swapfile.

[Here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/2vNKKh2Bcn/) is a Pastebin with boot-repair output.

`ls -al /` shows:

```
total 16777312

drwxr-xr-x  20  root    root            4096        mar 16  18:09   .
drwxr-xr-x  20  root    root            4096        mar 16  18:09   ..
lrwxrwxrwx  1   root    root            7           mar 14  07:09   bin -> usr/bin
drwxr-xr-x  4   root    root            4096        apr 22  07:02   boot
drwxrwxr-x  2   root    root            4096        mar 14  07:11   cdrom
drwxr-xr-x  21  root    root            4800        may 2   05:57   dev
drwxr-xr-x  141 root    root            12288       may 1   08:39   etc
drwxr-xr-x  3   root    root            4096        mar 14  07:11   home
lrwxrwxrwx  1   root    root            7           mar 14  07:09   lib -> usr/lib
lrwxrwxrwx  1   root    root            9           mar 14  07:09   lib32 -> usr/lib32
lrwxrwxrwx  1   root    root            9           mar 14  07:09   lib64 -> usr/lib64
lrwxrwxrwx  1   root    root            10          mar 14  07:09   libx32 -> usr/libx32
drwx------  2   root    root            16384       mar 14  07:09   lost+found
drwxr-xr-x  3   root    root            4096        mar 14  17:51   media
drwxr-xr-x  3   root    root            4096        apr 1   17:19   mnt
drwxr-xr-x  3   root    root            4096        mar 14  07:47   opt
dr-xr-xr-x  246 root    root            0           may 2   05:57   proc
drwx------  9   root    root            4096        apr 25  16:10   root
drwxr-xr-x  30  root    root            880         may 2   05:57   run
lrwxrwxrwx  1   root    root            8           mar 14  07:09   sbin -> usr/sbin
drwxr-xr-x  29  root    root            4096        apr 29  14:22   snap
drwxr-xr-x  2   root    root            4096        okt 12  2021    srv
-rw-------  1   root    root     17179869184        mar 16  18:34   swapfile
dr-xr-xr-x  13  root    root            0           may 2   05:57   sus
drwxrwxrwt  8   root    root            12288       may 1   08:40   tmp
drwxr-xr-x  15  root    root            4096        apr 6   18:08   usr
drwxr-xr-x  14  root    root            4096        okt 12  2021    var
```

`cat /proc/mounts` shows:

```
/dev/nvme0n1p2  /           ext4 ro,relatime 0 0
/dev/nvme0n1p2  /mnt/hd2    ext4 ro,relatime 0 0
/dev/nvme0n1p1  /boot/efi   vfat rw,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro 0 0
```

It seems I somehow managed to mount the root partition also as a non-root mount folder, which I'm guessing is incorrect.

Device SMART data (this is an NVMe SSD):

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo nvme smart-log /dev/nvme0
Smart Log for NVME device:nvme0 namespace-id:ffffffff
critical_warning                        : 0
temperature                             : 29 C
available_spare                         : 100%
available_spare_threshold               : 10%
percentage_used                         : 1%
endurance group critical warning summary: 0
data_units_read                         : 15,270,156
data_units_written                      : 12,745,135
host_read_commands                      : 158,291,363
host_write_commands                     : 162,929,827
controller_busy_time                    : 4,393
power_cycles                            : 1,257
power_on_hours                          : 1,912
unsafe_shutdowns                        : 43
media_errors                            : 0
num_err_log_entries                     : 0
Warning Temperature Time                : 0
Critical Composite Temperature Time     : 0
Thermal Management T1 Trans Count       : 116
Thermal Management T2 Trans Count       : 0
Thermal Management T1 Total Time        : 464
Thermal Management T2 Total Time        : 0
```

Read-only filesystem troubleshooting:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 465.76 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: KINGSTON SA2000M8500G                   
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: F7DDADFD-E9EA-445D-8A89-E71D0688372F

Device           Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1    2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2 1050624 976771071 975720448 465.3G Linux filesystem

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fsck -f /dev/nvme0n1p2
fsck from util-linux 2.36.1
e2fsck 1.46.3 (27-Jul-2021)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
/dev/nvme0n1p2: 570684/30498816 files (0.9% non-contiguous), 86783963/121965056 blocks
```

Output of `grep -i nvme /var/log/syslog*` (somewhat abridged):

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ grep -i nvme /var/log/syslog*
/var/log/syslog: systemd-fsck[811]: /dev/nvme0n1p1: 20 file, 2337/130812 clusters
/var/log/syslog: kernel: nvme nvme0: pci function 0000:02:00.0
/var/log/syslog: kernel: nvme nvme0: missing or invalid SUBNQN field.
/var/log/syslog: kernel: nvme nvme0: 4/0/0 default/read/poll queues
/var/log/syslog: kernel: nvme nvme0: nvme0n1: p1 p2
/var/log/syslog: kernel: nvme nvme0: EXT4-fs (nvme0n1p2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null). Quota mode: none.
/var/log/syslog: kernel: nvme nvme0: EXT4-fs (nvme0n1p2): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro. Quota mode: none.
/var/log/syslog: sensors[942]: nvme-pci-0200
```

Maybe the remounting is happening because we have two entries in `/proc/mounts`?

Output of `cat /etc/fstab` (somewhat abridged):

```
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=D3D0-8EA5    /boot/efi    vfat     umask=0077    0    1
/swapfile                               none         swap  sw    0    0
UUID=7815fe4f-cefe-49da-ba97-e12382a98395 /mnt/hd2 ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1
```

Output of `ls -al /boot` after commenting out `/swapfile` line from `/etc/fstab`:

```
ls -al /boot

total 116196

drwxr-xr-x  20  root    root            4096        apr 22  07:02   .
drwxr-xr-x  20  root    root            4096        mar 16  18:09   ..
-rw-r--r--  1   root    root            257253      mar 24  16:24   config-5.13.0-39-generic
-rw-r--r--  1   root    root            257253      mar 29  16:09   config-5.13.0-40-generic
drwx------  3   root    root            4096        jan 1   1970    efi
drwxr-xr-x  4   root    root            4096        apr 20  06:22   grub
lrwxrwxrwx  1   root    root            28          apr 20  06:21   initrd.img -> initrd.img-5.13.0-40-generic
-rw-r--r--  1   root    root            43008308    mar 31  06:21   initrd.img-5.13.0-39-generic
-rw-r--r--  1   root    root            42423530    apr 22  07:02   initrd.img-5.13.0-40-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1   root    root            28          apr 20  06:21   initrd.img.old -> initrd.img-5.13.0-39-generic
-rw-r--r--  1   root    root            182704      oct 7   2021    memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r--  1   root    root            184380      oct 7   2021    memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r--  1   root    root            184884      oct 7   2021    memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw-------  1   root    root            5975219     mar 24  16:24   System.map-5.13.0-39-generic
-rw-------  1   root    root            5976259     mar 29  16:09   System.map-5.13.0-40-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1   root    root            25          apr 20  06:21   vmlinuz -> vmlinux-5.13.0-40-generic
-rw-------  1   root    root            10242240    mar 24  16:27   vmlinuz-5.13.0-39-generic
-rw-------  1   root    root            5975219     mar 24  16:13   vmlinuz-5.13.0-40-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1   root    root            25          apr 20  06:21   vmlinuz -> vmlinux-5.13.0-39-generic
```

Output of `sudo filefrag -v /swapfile |grep " 0:"| awk '{print $4}'`

`98336768..`

Output of `grep -i GRUB /etc/default/grub`:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=UUID=7815fe4f-cefe-49da-ba97-e12382a98395 resume_offset=98336768"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"
# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480
# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"
# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Comment: Boot Repair is not for such issues and in this case its report is useless. Boot Repair deals ONLY with bootloader issues. Your issue is some steps after any bootloader and if it takes you to Xubuntu, irrespective of the reported errors, then it's no longer a Grub issue. For such problem I would be looking at `fstab` and check whether or not what's there regarding swap matches reality.

Comment: In the terminal, show me `free -h` and `swapon -s` and `grep -i swap /etc/fstab`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema

`free -h` shows:

`total used free shared buff/cache available
Mem: 15Gi 218Mi 14Gi 9,0Mi 400Mi   15Gi
Swap: 0B  0B  0B`

`swapon -s` didn't show anything.

`grep -i swap /etc/fstab` shows:

`/swapfile    none    swap sw  0 0`

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al /`.

Comment: @heynnema

I've added output of `ls -al /` to the question. Also added a comment to your answer below - not sure what you get notified about. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**R/O file system**

**Your file system has become read-only.**

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

---

**Now we fix the real problem causing read-only mode of your SSD.**

Boot to Recovery Mode, Root Access

In the `terminal`...

`sudo mount -o rw,remount /` # to remount the SSD in r/w mode.

Edit /etc/fstab...

change...

```
UUID=7815fe4f-cefe-49da-ba97-e12382a98395 /mnt/hd2 ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1
```

to

```
UUID=7815fe4f-cefe-49da-ba97-e12382a98395 / ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1
```

And uncomment the /swapfile line that we commented out earlier.

Save the file and reboot normally.

`free -h` # confirm that /swapfile shows properly

---

**SWAP/HIBERNATION**

We add resume= and resume_offset= to /etc/default/grub.

In the `terminal`...

`sudo filefrag -v /swapfile |grep " 0:"| awk '{print $4}`

Note the number printed.

Edit /etc/default/grub.

change...

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=UUID=7815fe4f-cefe-49da-ba97-e12382a98395 resume_offset=98336768"
```

`sudo update-grub`

`reboot`

---

**SSD firmware**

Install the newer SSD firmware from https://github.com/vulgo/kingston-a2000-firmware-bin-linux. This pro-ports to solve "Fixed an issue that might cause the drive to become unresponsive on Linux systems".

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136039/discussion-on-answer-by-heynnema-how-can-i-fix-this-failed-to-activate-swap-sw).